# How do I connect containers using container name with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to understand how I access containers between each other through their container name. Specifically when using a pgadmin container and connecting to a postgresql container through dns.

In docker-compose V3 , I cannot link them, nor does `networks:` seem to be available either.

The main reason to need this is when the containers spin up they don't have a static IP address, so in pgadmin I can't connect to the postgresql DB using the same IP every time , so a dns name would work better (ie: the container name).

Can we do this with docker-compose or at least set a static ip address for a specific container?

I have tried creating a user defined network:

```
networks:
  backed:
```

and then using it in the service:

```
app:
  networks:
    - backend
```

This causes a docker-compose error regarding an invalid option of "networks" in the app.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "0.1"

services:
  devapi:
    container_name: devapi
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  api-postgres-pgadmin:
    container_name: api-postgres-pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=stuff@stuff.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=12345

  api-postgres:
    container_name: api-postgres
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345
```

Comment: Can you clarify this sentence more "I am trying to understand how I access containers between each other through their container name. "?  Also, why can't you use the host-name to communicate between containers?

Comment: Also, your example `docker-compose.yml` doesn't show your (attempted) use of `networks`. Can you update it to include that? It might highlight why you're seeing that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I spot one immediate problem:

```
version: "0.1"
```

Why are you doing this?  The current version of the compose file format is 3.x. E.g:

```
version: "3"
```

See e.g. the [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

The version determines which feature are available. It's entirely possible that by setting `version: "0.1"` you are explicitly disabling support for the `networks` parameter. You'll note that the [reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) shows examples using the `networks` attribute.

As an aside, unless there is a particular reason you ened it, I would drop the use of the `container_name` in your compose file, since this makes it impossible to run multiple instances of the same `compose` file on your host.

Answer (score 0):

`networks` are available from docker-compose version 3 but you are using `version:"0.1"` in your docker-compose file.

Change the `version: "0.1"` to `version: "3"` in docker-compose.yml.